# Get the ID of element using the starting word of string present in it using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I know the starting word of the string present in the h2 element. How to find the ID of that element using contains?

The string present inside h2 is 'What Repairs Can Fix A P0500 Trouble Code?'. The sub string 'P0500' varies so it is not known. Is there a way to find the id using only the known words of the string.

```js
const word = 'P0500';
let id = $(`h2:contains(${word})`).attr('id');

console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 id="heading2">What Repairs Can Fix A P0500 Trouble Code?</h2>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not completely match"? Maybe add some HTML for reference.

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: But you haven't explained why the posted code doesn't work (since it does), what's the problem you're trying to solve? And where are you stuck? What's the (relevant, "*[mcve]*") code to reproduce that problem?

Comment: I've added a snippet demonstrating what I understand your situation to be. Please revise it to show the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's working fine for me. I added a working snippet for the reference.

```js
let id = $('h2:contains("test")').attr('id');

console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 id="1">div1</h2>
<h2 id="2">This is a test, nested in div1</h2>
<h2 id="3">Nested in div1<h2>
```

Comment: It was a simple case sensitive issue in my code. Thank You

Comment: If this answer doesn't resolve the actual problem it shouldn't be accepted. If there is no solution, please delete your question.

Comment: ^^ or add your own solution that does resolve the problem

Comment: This answer seems like a comment to me. I don't see anything that attempts to solve the problem.